# Sudo can't create file in /usr/bin in El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I upgraded to El Capitan yesterday and everything was good until recently when I noticed I can't write anything (with sudo ofc) on /usr/bin as I tried to install phpbrew.

What could be causing this and how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: OS X El Capitan is rootless. The feature can be disabled from the recovery partition.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since OSX 10.11, Apple reinforced the security system. Called [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), Apple locks down:

```
/System
/sbin
/usr (with the exception of /usr/local subdirectory)
```

To disable this security feature you have to reboot your computer and hold `CMD+R` at start to boot into OS X Recovery Mode.

Then `OS X Utilities > Terminal`

Type the command `csrutil disable; reboot`

Your computer will restart. You will see a confirmation message about the desactivation.

To verified the status of CRS type `csrutil status`

Comment: I disabled and it still doesn't allow me to do anything:
```/Users/Rob$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
/Users/Rob$ touch /usr/bin/yes
touch: /usr/bin/yes: Permission denied```

Comment: Try with `sudo`.

Comment: In most cases, it's better to install local customizations into /usr/local (e.g. /usr/local/bin rather than /bin or /usr/bin). That's what it's for, and this has been the case for a long time. If possible, I'd recommend following this best practice rather than disabling SIP. If you really do need to make changes in a restricted location, it's best to disable SIP, make the change, and then immediately re-enable SIP with `csrutil enable` (in Recovery mode).

Answer (score 8):

As [mentioned by Ragnar](https://superuser.com/a/1000037/117042), the `/usr` directory is locked down by the system, with the exception of `/usr/local`. Then, if your scenario allows, I'd recommend adding the symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin`. If you don't have a strict requirement on using `/usr/bin`, that's one way to work around the "Operation not permitted" error.

Answer (score 2):

One can verify if a particular file or directory is restricted by OSX's System Integrity Protection (SIP)/Rootless by listing the file flags using the `-O` option to ls (e.g. to see which directories in / are restricted):

```
ls -Ol /
```

The directories or files that are controlled by SIP show as 'restricted'.

There's full details in the answers to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) about SIP/rootless.